# Visual Studio: Change Directory for Opening Text Files

Tags: visual-studio, directory, text-files

My program won't open text files unless I place them in the Debug folder. When I put the files there, the program runs, but they don't save when I commit and push my changes to GitHub. I think it's because the text files are in the Debug folder and not with the source files/project folder. Is there a way that I can change how the program runs so it executes the text files with the source files?

[The program when the files are in the project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkyf3.png)

[The program when the text files are in the Debug folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0gXO.png)

[GitHub doesn't show the Debug folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zd5n.png)

[Debug folder (local)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTc2E.png)

I put the text files in the Debug folder expecting it to work, and it did. However, since they are in the Debug folder, they aren't included in my commits to GitHub. I want to fix the issue so I don't have version control issues down the line.